# How do I modify outgoing SIP messages from Yate?

Tags: sip, voip

I need to strip the rport parameter from the Via field of SIP messages being generated by Yate (for compatibility with a broken peer). Can I use the scripting capabilities of Yate to do this? How do I intercept and modify outgoing SIP messages?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered, by reading the code, that Yate already supports this feature. In accfile.conf, in the section defining the sip server to register to, place the following line:

```
xsip_flags=1
```

This prevents the rport parameter from being placed in SIP messages. This may break routing if you are behind a NAT, so beware.

An example config would therefore be:

```
[sip_service]
enabled=yes
protocol=sip
description=sip_service
username=user
domain=somewhere.com
authname=auth
password=secret
server=somewhere.com
xsip_flags=1
```